# Why is my front crank clicking/creaking?

Tags: noise, front, clicking

I've purchased a new bike. Carrera Hellcat is the model.

I'm getting a click noise from the front crank but only when the middle sprocket has the chain on it, there are 3 at the front. There are around 10 small click sounds per every rotation. I'm just wondering if anyone knows what it could be.

I've tightened the chain ring bolts and the bottom bracket a bit but the problem is still there.

Does any one have any ideas?

Seems odd that there's no click on the other front gears.

Cheers!

Comment: Is the click regularly periodically repeating, or random?

Comment: Is it coming from the spindle, the crank arm, pedal or the chainring?  Is the front shifter indexed?  Can you post a clip of the sound?

Comment: The front derailleur is probably not properly tuned. If you bought your bike at a bike shop, take it back and have them take a look. Fine tuning after the first rides is usually part of the deal at any decent bike store. It may be a bit more problematic if you bought it online or at a department store. In that case you'd have to find a workshop that is willing to do the job, and you'd have to pay for it.

Comment: Adding to what @Carel posted, while you're riding your bike with the chain on the middle chainring and the clicking happening, start to try shifting the chain to the large chainring - but don't actually do the shift.  Just start slowly applying more pressure to your shift lever.  When you start putting tension on the shift cable, that will probably force the front derailleur to move a little bit.  If that pressure changes the clicking - makes it go away, makes it louder, makes it more or less frequent - the problem is the chain rubbing on the derailleur when you're on the middle chainring.

Comment: (cont)  If applying pressure like that doesn't change the clicking, it proves nothing either way.  But it's an easy test to do.  And do the test someplace wide open and empty.  You're going to be focused on shifting and listening.  You don't want to be doing that where you can run into someone or something, or fail to notice something about to run into you.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the front shifter metal cage. Is the chain touching it? It is the most likely problem. It may be more apparent with certain gears  in the rear than with others.

If yes, shift to the middle in the back. Try to turn the barrel adjuster on your left shifter one way and back. Does the noise change? It should and you should be able to find a position where it does not rub.

After doing that you may need to adjust the limit screws for the inner and the outer chainring.